# Why @wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef; is causing following JS error

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, navigation, lightningnavigation, navigationmixin.navigate

Line: "@wire(CurrentPageReference) pageRef;" in lwc is causing following js error in console log. What is the fix?

```
Error: [LWC error]: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in 
element <c-lineitemdetail-header-component>. Event name must 1) Start with a 
lowercase letter 2) Contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores
<c-lineitemdetail-header-component>
at Object.logError (aura_proddebug.js:4268)
at ConstructionEstimation.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:7622)
at ConstructionEstimation.wrappedMethod [as dispatchEvent] (aura_proddebug.js:12985)
at WireEventTarget.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:9501)
at d.get (contextService.js:2)
at eval (contextService.js:2)
at E (contextService.js:2)
at Object.t.getContextValue (contextService.js:2)
at c.getCurrentPageReference (pageService.js:2)
at eval (navigation.js:2)
```

Comment: Did you add this import ? import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

Comment: Can you tell why are you using page reference in LWC....like your use case???

Comment: Yes I did add import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";

Comment: I am using page reference to get record id from previous page.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should still be able to get pagereference and just ignore the error.  This code still works:
(taken from https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/auraPubsub and slightly modified to @wire `CurrentPageReference` to a function instead of a variable )

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
import {
    registerListener,
    unregisterListener,
    unregisterAllListeners,
    fireEvent
} from 'c/pubsub';

export default class AuraPubsub extends LightningElement {
    pageRef;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    wirePageRef(data){
        if(data){
            this.pageRef = data;
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('ready'));
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
    }

    @api
    registerListener(eventName, callback) {
        registerListener(eventName, callback, this);
    }

    @api
    unregisterListener(eventName, callback) {
        unregisterListener(eventName, callback, this);
    }

    @api
    unregisterAllListeners() {
        unregisterAllListeners(this);
    }

    @api
    fireEvent(eventName, data) {
        fireEvent(this.pageRef, eventName, data);
    }
}
```

Looks like this is being worked on by the LWC team, we may need to wait for a release: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/1357

It looks like this used to be a warning, but was changed to an error here https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/pull/1193